# Echo gives multiple 'columns' instead of one list

Tags: php, list

I wrote the following code:

```
foreach ($key['options'] as $options) {
$contents = str_replace("[OPTION]",$options['text'], $contents);
}

$result= '';

foreach ($key['motor'] as $motor) {
$nm = str_replace ("[NAME]",$motor['name'], $contents);
$cnt = str_replace ("[COUNT]",$motor['count'], $contents);

$result .= $cnt ." " .$nm. " ";
}

echo $result;

$paginas .= $contents;

echo $paginas;
```

My '$key' looks like:

```
function getCarDetail($data){

$files = @file_get_contents("./assets/template/_detail.html");
$contents = "";
$paginas = "";

foreach ($data as $key) {

        $contents = str_replace("[PHOTO]",$key['photo'], $files);
        $contents = str_replace("[NAME]",$key['name'], $contents);
        $contents = str_replace("[TYPE]",$key['type'], $contents);

foreach ($key['step'] as $step) {
        $contents = str_replace("[STEP]",$step['text'], $contents);
            }

foreach ($key['comments'] as $comments) {
              $contents = str_replace("[COMMENTS]",$comments['text'], $contents);
            }

$result='';
foreach ($key['motor'] as $motor) {
$nm = str_replace ("[NAME]",$motor['name'], $contents);
$cnt = str_replace ("[COUNT]",$motor['count'], $contents);

$result .= $cnt ." " .$nm. " ";
}

echo $result;


$paginas .= $contents;

}

echo $paginas;

}



$layout = new _layout(getCarDetail($data, $key), DETAILPAGE);
echo $layout->render();
```

I have a (test) website about cars that contains 3 columns next to each other. Per car one column with the information I request via MySQL. That worked fine.

Now with the $result, I'd like to add more information to these columns, but there are multiple options per car.  Instead of listing all the $results in one column, it makes for each item a new column.

My goal is to get one overview where all the results from the $result are listed in 1 column.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12" align="center">
<dt>

</dt>
        <img src="[PHOTO]" img width="30%" img height="50%"    align="center"/>
        <dl>

            <dt>
                NAME
            </dt>
            <dd>
                [NAME]
            </dd>
    <dt>
                TYPE
            </dt>
            <dd>
                [TYPE]
            </dd>

            <dt>
                MOTOR
            </dt>
            <dd>
                  [COUNT] [MOTOR]
            </dd>

        </dl>

    </div>
```

_Layout:

```
class _layout {

private $template;


public function render() {
    return($this->template);
}




private function homepage($data) {
    $this->template = str_replace("[TITLE]", "Overview", $this-    >template);
    $this->template = str_replace("[CONTENT]", $data, $this->template);
}




private function detailpage($data) {
    $this->template = str_replace("[TITLE]", "Cars", $this->template);
    $this->template = str_replace("[CONTENT]", $data, $this->template);
}


private function list($data) {
    $this->template = str_replace("[TITLE]", "List", $this->template);
    $this->template = str_replace("[CONTENT]", "!", $this->template);
}



public function __construct($data,  $type) {

    $this->template = file_get_contents(TEMPLATE);

    switch($type) {

        case HOMEPAGE: {
            $this->homepage($data);
            break;
        }

        case DETAILPAGE: {
             $this->detailpage($data);
             break;
        }

        case LIST: {
            $this->list($data);
            break;
        }

        default: {
            $this->homepage($data);
            break;
        }
    }

}



}


?>
```

Anyone a clue how I can solve this?

Comment: Can you paste the actual output of the echo and also what you expected the output to be?

Comment: This is an example of how the echo looks like:
http://imgur.com/a/TVPwx

I expect that in this example one column list all what is here called "ingredienten". So not one column 4, the other column Pasta etc. But one column that shows 4 Pasta (and all the other items).

Comment: I don't really see how this image and your code example are related. Is this a HTML/CSS display issue? If so, you should add more information about `$key`. Does this contain the HTML code?

Comment: Is it a display issue? Is it not the $result code that is wrong and that's why it doesn't list ? I added the HTML code in my first post.

Comment: I think your question is still lacking a lot of information in order to answer it.  For instance, if you HTML code consists of `<dt>` and `<dd>`, how do you end up with 3 columns?

Comment: Well, I added some HTML code to the main post. This makes it 1 column on fullscreen, but still, it puts everything in a separate column instead of 1.

Comment: I think this is still not a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If I copy your html snipped several times into a html document, it shows up as one column. (Besides, there are other issues, i.e. drop the `img` from `img width` and `img height`.)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS class `col-md-12` indicates that you are using a BOOTSTRAP layout. Bootrap provides easy-to-use grid layouts with columns ([tutorial about boostrap grid](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)). A grid layout with thee columns can be created with `col-md-4` classes (the number indicates the width of the column, the full line has a width of 12). Since you want the opposite (only one column) you could remove all boostrap classes, or make sure that each item spans the full line by using the class `col-md-12`.

Comment: I deleted this, but then he still puts columns on top of each other. He is not making a list in 1 column. He puts the output of the $result in different columns.

Comment: In order to answer in more detail (more specific) you should provide the complete HTML which doesn't look right and additionally the content of `$key`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I added the requested info in my first post.

Comment: I still find it difficult to answer this in more detail. How does `./assets/template/_detail.html` look like? Whats the definition of `_layout`?

Comment: _detail is the HTML code as shown. I added the  _layout code.